# Python3.6 on Cygwin can't install modules

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin, python-module

I am trying to run a program on cygwin that uses "import numpy as np" and other modules.
when I try to compile the program on cygwin (using python3.6) I get an error message that the module is not found [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE5K2.png)

I have updated my pip3 and when I try to do "pip3 install numpy" i get errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwr6L.png)

Comment: Please place your console output in your question.

Comment: Ditto. Your screenshot does not include the error.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is already provided as Cygwin packages, there is no need to install with pip
but you need to install with setup. After that

```
$ cygcheck -c python36
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python36             3.6.13-1       OK

$ cygcheck -c python36-numpy
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python36-numpy       1.19.4-1       OK
```

as I have both the two packages:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.13 (default, Feb 16 2021, 07:46:47)
[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
```

Please note also that the preferred package on cygwin is python 3.8
So same is valid with python38 and python38-numpy